# Rails 7 can not set format turbo_stream with form method get

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

```rb
<%= form_with url: search_orders_path do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

It sends a request with turbo_stream format but when I change method to get(view and routes) it sends it as html:

```rb
<%= form_with url: search_orders_path, method: :get do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

I want to make a form with get method and turbo format

Answer (score 5):

For *GET* forms and links you have to specify that you want to send a *TURBO_STREAM* request:

```rb
<%= form_with url: search_orders_path, method: :get,
   data: {turbo_stream: true} do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/attributes*