# Rails 7 Turbo Stream renders black page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hotwire-rails, turbo

In my Rails 7 app I've got a simple web form where user has an input text field and submit button. After user provide some text inside of the field and push the submit button, 3rd party request is sent to fetch image url. After successful fetching, fetched image is displaying right next the form. The idea is that form submission is handled asynchronously, without a full page reload.

I thought it's super simple, check my controller:

```
class DogsController < ApplicationController
  def index; end

  def fetch_image
    url = fetch_url

    render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace('dog_image_frame', partial: 'dog_image', locals: { url: })
  end

  private

  def fetch_url = client.breeds_show(params[:breed]).message
  def client = @client ||= DogCeo::Client.new
end
```

Code inside `app/views/dogs/index.slim`:

```
.ms-3
  h2.mt-4.mb-5.text-primary
    = t('.header')
  .row
    .col-md-6
      = render Dogs::NewFormComponent.new
    .col-md-6
      = turbo_frame_tag 'dog_image_frame' do
        | No Image Fetched Yet
```

The app/components/dogs/new_form_component.slim:

```
= form_with url: fetch_image_dogs_path, method: :get, id: 'dog-form' do |f|
  = render(Forms::TextFieldComponent.new(form: f, field: :breed, label: label_text, autofocus: true, required: true, name: 'dog[breed]'))
  = render(Forms::SubmitComponent.new(form: f))
```

And finally `app/views/dogs/_dog_image.slim`:

```
img src="#{url}" alt="Fetched Dog Image"
```

I think everything was setup correctly, I've no clue what should I change since with this code, after user's submission, I'm getting below black page with information:

```
<turbo-stream action="replace" target="users_index"><template><img alt="Fetched Dog Image" src="https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/mastiff-tibetan/n02108551_5216.jpg" /></template></turbo-stream>
```

[image]

**[Edit]**

Server logs below, no any error on web console:

```
Started GET "/dogs/fetch_image?breed=mastiff&commit=Submit" for ::1 at 2023-10-07 08:57:04 +0200
Processing by DogsController#fetch_image as HTML
  Parameters: {"breed"=>"mastiff", "commit"=>"Submit"}
I, [2023-10-07T08:57:04.255156 #35576]  INFO -- request: GET https://dog.ceo/api/breed/mastiff/images/random
I, [2023-10-07T08:57:04.439900 #35576]  INFO -- response: Status 200
  Rendered dogs/_dog_image.slim (Duration: 2.9ms | Allocations: 2103)
Completed 200 OK in 202ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 9416)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76283733/207090

Comment: @Alex that doesn't change anything. I added `data: { turbo_stream: true }` into `form_with` and still gets the same result.

Comment: gonna need some details. like logs, do you get "Processing by ... as TURBO_STREAM"?

Comment: @Alex I don't think you will find anything interesting here, hope I'm wrong. Post updated.

Comment: `as HTML` is an issue. do you have any forms that submit `as TURBO_STREAM`? maybe your Turbo set up is broken. to double check, open your browser console and type: Turbo.

Comment: No, I just have this one page in the entire app. When I typed `Turbo` in browser console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Turbo is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1`. I haven't change anything after `rails new my_new_app --skip-test --css=bootstrap && cd estatesearch_app && bundle add rspec-rails --group 'development, test' && rails generate rspec:install`. Isn't that Turbo in Rails 7 is build in feature and you don't need to do anything to make it useful? because I didn't do anything extra.

Comment: are you running `bin/dev`? and does javascript part compiles successfully?

Comment: @Alex omg no, I simply ran `rails s`. Now everything works as expected, lol. Thanks!